# Update Pictures In cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have an Up which has to do a lot with pictures. I have a problem. I know might seems stupid, and even i know that im missing something, but i havent found out yet. So in few words. Let's say I have an Item. |id|name|price|condition|location|picture|

**picture** is the picture path that i save to DB. So when i create a new Item all the field are required. Till here everything works Fine.Now lets say i open Item x to edit. I edit only the name and the price and other i leave them as they are, and i press save, browse button, of the picture field is still required and i have to open galerry find the pic again in order to save. So  my question is this: How can i do a picture upload only if i browse for the picture,  but not to forget that on creation must not be empty. To Ilustrate it here is some code:

```
   <?php
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class Item extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Item';

        public $primaryKey = 'id';
        public $displayField = 'title';

        public $validate = array(
            'id' => array(
                'blank' => array(
                    'rule' => 'blank',
                    'on' => 'create',
                ),
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'words' => array(
                    'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                    'message' => 'The Item name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
                ),
                'maxLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
                    'message' => 'The Item name must not be longer than 100 characters.',
                ),
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'The Item name must not be empty.',
                ),
                'isUnique' => array(
                     'rule' => 'isUnique',
                     'message' => 'This Item name already exists.',
                ),
            ),
            'picture' => array(
                'uploadError' => array(
                    'rule'=>'uploadError',
                    'message' => 'The File Did NOT Upload. Please Try Again!',              
                ),
                'fileSize'=>array(
                   'rule'=>array('fileSize','<=','30MB'),
                   'message'=>'File Size should be less then 30MB',         
                ),
                'processMediaUpload'=>array(
                    'rule' =>'processMediaUpload',
                    'message'=>'Uploading File Failed!',            
                ),
            ),
            'item_location_id' => array(
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'You Must Choose a Location',
                ),
                'numeric' => array(
                    'rule' => array('numeric'),
                    //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                ),
            ),
            'address' => array(
                'words' => array(
                    'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                    'message' => 'The Item Address can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
                ),
                'maxLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 150),
                    'message' => 'Address can not be longer then 150 characters long',
                ),
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'You Should Put an Address',
                ),
            ),

        );


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemLocation' => array(
            'className' => 'ItemLocation',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_location_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),

    );



    public function processMediaUpload($mediacheck = array()) {
    $dir = 'img/uploads/item/media/';
        if (isset($mediacheck['media_path']['name'])) {  
            if(is_uploaded_file($mediacheck['media_path']['tmp_name'])) {           
                 if (trim($mediacheck['media_path']['name'])!=""){
                // here we delete if the image exist and replace it.
                    if (file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $dir . $mediacheck['media_path']['name'])) { 
                     unlink(WWW_ROOT . $dir . $mediacheck['media_path']['name']); 
                     return true;
                    } 
                } 
                $allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif');
                $extension=strtolower(end(explode(".", $mediacheck['media_path']['name']))); 
                if (($mediacheck['media_path']['size'] < 55000000)) { 
                    if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
                        if ($mediacheck['media_path']["error"] > 0) {   
                            $this->invalidate('media_path', $mediacheck['media_path']['error']);
                            return false;  
                        } else  {      
                            if (file_exists( WWW_ROOT . $dir) && is_dir( WWW_ROOT . $dir))  { 
                                if (file_exists( WWW_ROOT . $dir . $mediacheck['media_path']['name'])) { 
                                    $this->invalidate('media_path', 'File Allredy Exists!');
                                    return false;     
                                } else {    
                                move_uploaded_file($mediacheck['media_path']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dir .  mktime() . $mediacheck['media_path']['name']);
                                $this->data[$this->alias]['media_path'] =  mktime() . $mediacheck['media_path']['name'];
                                return TRUE;
                                }
                            } else {  // in this case the directory doesent exist so we create it
                                mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                            move_uploaded_file($mediacheck['media_path']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dir .  mktime() . $mediacheck['media_path']['name']);
                            $this->data[$this->alias]['media_path'] = mktime() . $mediacheck['media_path']['name'];
                            return TRUE;
                            }
                        }
                    }else { $this->invalidate('media_path', 'Invalid File Format! ');   return false;}
                } else {  $this->invalidate('media_path', 'File size is To big!');  return false;  }
            } else { $this->invalidate('media_path', 'You must upload a file before you Submit!');  return false;  } 
        } else { $this->invalidate('media_path', 'You must upload a file before you Submit!');  return false; }      
     // better safe then sorry!
     return false;
    }
```

**Add Form:**

```
<div class="items form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Item', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add New Item'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('item_description');
    echo $this->Form->input('location_description');
    echo $this->Form->input('media_path', array('label'=>'Media','type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('item_location_id', array('label'=>'Location'));
    echo $this->Form->input('item_characteristic_id', array('label'=>'Characteristics'));
    echo $this->Form->input('address', array('id' => 'address'));
    echo  "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width:98%; height:400px;\"> </div>";
    echo $this->Form->input('longitude', array('id'=>'longitude', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
    echo $this->Form->input('latitude', array('id'=>'latitude', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_seller_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('second_seller_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('brochure_path', array('label'=>'Broshure','type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_title');
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_description' , array('label' => 'SEO Description'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_url' , array('label' => 'SEO Url'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_keywords' , array('label' => 'SEO Keywords'));
?>
</fieldset>
```

**Edit Form:**

```
<div class="items form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Item', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit Item'); ?></legend>
<?php
    $dir = "/img/uploads/item/media/"; 
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('item_description');
    echo $this->Form->input('location_description');
    echo $this->Form->input('media_path', array('label'=>'Media','type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('hiddenimage', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=> $this->Form->value('media_path') )); 
    $Image = $this->Form->value( 'media_path');     
        if(empty($Image) || $Image==NULL)
                {$Image = "/img/uploads/noimg.jpg";}
            else {$Image = $dir . $Image;   }
    echo $this->Html->image($Image,array('align'=>'absbottom','style'=>'max-height:100px'));
    echo "<h3> Test: ". $this->Form->value('media_path') . "</h3>";

    echo $this->Form->input('item_location_id', array('label'=>'Location'));
    echo $this->Form->input('item_characteristic_id', array('label'=>'Characteristics'));
    echo $this->Form->input('address', array('id' => 'address'));
    echo  "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width:98%; height:400px;\"> </div>";
    echo $this->Form->input('longitude', array('id'=>'longitude', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
    echo $this->Form->input('latitude', array('id'=>'latitude', 'readonly'=>'readonly'));
    echo $this->Form->input('first_seller_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('second_seller_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('brochure_path', array('label'=>'Broshure','type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_title');
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_description' , array('label' => 'SEO Description'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_url' , array('label' => 'SEO Url'));
    echo $this->Form->input('seo_keywords' , array('label' => 'SEO Keywords'));
?>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at adding the [on parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on) to your rules.

```
'on' => 'create'
```

Will only trigger the validation on an `insert` (i.e. a new record).

> If a rule has defined ‘on’ => ‘create’, the rule will only be enforced
>   during the creation of a new record. Likewise, if it is defined as
>   ‘on’ => ‘update’, it will only be enforced during the updating of a
>   record.

Comment: To you picture rules, you forgot to mention that, he already has on for id.

Answer (score 0):

In your edit action could you not just check the field and remove it if it's empty? Is that what you mean? Like:

```
if (empty($this->request->data['Item']['media_path'])) {
    unset($this->request->data['Item']['media_path']);
}
```

It would probably be more complicated than that, checking to see if it's valid upload I guess, but would something like that work?

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: It doesent show anything. it just display message: Upload Failed. But the point is that when i edit the picture, and i edit only it;s name, i want to retain that pic. the same picture.  and not change it or re-upload it. and when i press save only when i make changes to its name it doesent save, it needs to re-upload the pic. I tried adding another field on validation criteria **edit_pic** and i  also added other rules **allowEmpty** as well. and write another upload function only for that purpose, but still No Go. :/

Comment: I understand what you mean - sometimes you only want to edit the meta data associated with a previously uploaded image. In that case you need to be able to call save() without validating the uploaded file field. Does that message ('Upload Failed') correspond to the 'message' from one of your custom validation methods? If so then that's what you need to fix

Comment: No The point is This: If i re-upload the image it uploads just fine. and it doesent dublicate.  i manage to do it right. but when i just change the names and i press save, upload field is required, and i have to reupload it.

Comment: Yes, I know - it's required because of your validation isn't it?  My original suggestion was to remove the file field from the request data if the field is empty. You'd then have to change your validation so that if the file field was *missing* (rather than just empty) the validation would accept that as valid.

Comment: Yes it is required because of my validation. but i want it to be required on creation, but not on update. Ok i can put on => create, but then when i update and dontupload a pic, it overwrite the path and there would be picture missing

Comment: Do you have any suggestiong how i could do that @toby1kenobi

Comment: You need to look at the custom validation function that is preventing your model from saving, and adapt it so that if the file field (in your data) is empty the validation passes (i.e. returns 'true')